# How do I get drivers working for an Nvidia GT560i on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg, xubuntu, update-manager

I been using a test Xubuntu 12.04 LTS on my 64 bit workstation, because [Ubuntu has dropped support for the nvidia graphic adapters my 10.04 LTS and I haven't been able to get them working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202206/how-do-i-get-drivers-working-for-an-nvidia-gt560i-on-10-04).

Now update manager has upgraded the kernel from 3.2.0-30-generic to 3.2.0-31-generic, and [failed to produce a working nvidia module that the X server can load](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1072791).

Fortunately, when launching the 3.2.0-30-generic kernel, I still have use of the X server.

Does anybody know a work-around or fix for this?

I'm really worried, this is the last working Ubuntu distribution OS on the computer and I don't want to give up on Ubuntu.

Details of problem [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1072791).

The system (hardware) successfully boots ArcLinux x86_64, Vista Ult 64, Windows XP x64.  Before problems with nvidia graphic adapters, the system boot successfully Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

The output of lspci -v is [here](http://pastebin.com/V2mG0Wti).

Comment: If all else fails, you may want to download and install directly from NVIDIA (http://askubuntu.com/questions/203497/why-cant-i-install-the-nvidia-304-60-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-amd64/203855#203855). You will need the kernel headers for successfully building the kernel module during installation. Good luck.

Comment: The answer was to wait until a later update from Ubuntu so it worked. BTW, the same thing happened again. Not as much fun as playing slots....

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with ubuntu 12.04 where some nVidia cards do not work with the nVidia drivers that are in the standard repository. As well, these cards will not boot the gui property.

I don't know if the same problem exists on Xubuntu, since I don't use it, but on the offchance that this is what is affecting you, then the information contained here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/fballem/Software%2012.04 may prove helpful.

I hope that this helps,

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The nvidia driver for the 3.2.0-30-generic kernel which works is the same one for the 3.2.0-31-generic which does not work.  The problem as reported by Xorg.0.log is that the nvidia module could not be found for the 3.2.0-31-generic kernel.  Why it finds it for the 3.2.0-30-generic and not the  3.2.0-31-generic kernel is inexplicable. :¬(